# Redirecting to another page without sending any value in query string

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to perform user verification when the user logs in for the first time. If the user is not verified already then i send its `userid` from  the code  to call back method
and in the callback I redirect it to another page using

```
(window.location.href = "/verifyuser?id=" + response.userId)
```

however i do not want it this way. instead i would like to do an ajax call to the url with the value. i don't want the userId to be visible in the url.
I tried using

```
$.ajax({

     type:"POST"        
     url:"/verifyuser",
     data:{id:response.userId},
     async:false
});
```

but it didn't work. My server side code is below(i am using mvc 4)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult VerifyUser(string id)
    {           
        ViewBag.Id = id;
        return View("~/Views/User/VerifyUser.cshtml");
    }
```

and my js code is below:

```
var postObj = {

            url: "Home/Login",
            data: {},
            callback: function (status, response) {
                if (response.status === 400) {
                    var errors = response.errors;
                    var serverValidate = new PS.Validate(userObj);
                    var isvalid = serverValidate.showErrors(errors);
                }
                else {

                    if (response.userId !== null && response.userId !== undefined) {

                        window.location.href = "/verifyuser?id=" + response.userId;
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location.href = "/user-dashboard";
                    }
                }
            }
        };
me.fm.post(postObj);
```

Is there any way to do this with or without Ajax? Thanks.

Comment: Your Ajax uses `POST` but you decorated with `[HttpGet]`

Comment: If the only reason for going down the ajax route is to stop values being shown in the querystring then just change the form method to `POST`.

Comment: What didn't work?  The request wasn't made?  The server didn't get the request?  The server returned an error?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do an ajax call you can return a RedirectToAction ActionResult in your controller but you will have to make sure the page does a actual form post not use ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you change your AJAX request to POST, you will also have to allow your controller action to respond to POST requests.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VerifyUser(string id)
{           
    ViewBag.Id = id;
    return View("~/Views/User/VerifyUser.cshtml");
}
```